# Reloading Custom Functions in Excel Add-In - Online Version

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I am working on an Excel Add-In with custom functions using the Javascript API. I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart?tabs=excel-windows) tutorial.

I am trying to debug this using the Web version of Excel as the logging capabilities are significantly better, however I am finding that it will never register changes in my `functions.ts` file. I can change any other code file (eg. `taskpane.ts`) and will see the changes reflected immediately, however whenever I try to reload the custom functions, I do not see any of the changes.

The commands I'm using:
`npm run build` followed by
`npm run watch` in one terminal, `npm run start:web` in another.

This is the same whether or not I run `npm run watch` in one terminal or not.

In order to observe any changes I need to completely restart the entire server and reload the plugin.

This makes for a pretty miserable development experience. Has anyone overcome issues like these, or have suggestions as to how I can improve the development process for Excel add-ins?

I would also like to develop using the Desktop version of excel, however do to the lack of decent logging capabilities, this doesn't seem too feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to hear you are having problems.  Can you please try the following:

- Open the project manifest and remove 'dist' from the functions.html url as follows:

[image]

- Run "npm run build" again and then "npm start" again

Comment: amazing. Yea, that seems to have resolved it!